# Vue SFC styles not being extracted in webpack production build

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-4, vue-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

Trying to add vue (and SFCs) to my webpack app.  The `<template>` and `<script>` blocks work fine, but for some reason the styles in the `<style>` block are not being extracted for production build.

In the dev build, it's extracting the .vue `<style>` block to a separate css file (named for the entrypoint). Which is OK but I'd prefer they went into my main stylesheet.

But no matter what I try, I can't get any .vue styles to show up (in *any* file) for the production build.

This is an abbreviated version of my webpack config:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const VueLoaderPlugin = require("vue-loader/lib/plugin");
...

module.exports = (env) => {
  return {
    entry: {
      app: ["./src/polyfills.js", "./src/scss/styles.scss", "./src/app.js"],
      ...
      testview: "./src/js/views/TestView.js"
    },
    output: {
      path: assets,
      filename: "[name].[hash].js",
      publicPath: "/static/"
    },
    resolve: {
      modules: ["node_modules", "src"],
      alias: {
        vue$: "vue/dist/vue.esm.js"
      },
      extensions: ["*", ".js", ".vue"]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          loader: "vue-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.js?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "babel-loader",
              options: {
                presets: [
                  [
                    "@babel/preset-env",
                    {
                      targets: {
                        browsers: ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "ie >= 11"]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                ],

                plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
                code: true,
                comments: true,
                cacheDirectory: true,
                babelrc: false
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
          use: [
            "vue-style-loader",
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: ifNotProduction()
              }
            },
            {
              loader: "postcss-loader",
              options: {
                ident: "postcss",
                sourceMap: ifNotProduction(),
                plugins: () =>
                  ifProduction([
                    require("autoprefixer")({
                      preset: "default"
                    }),
                    require("cssnano"),
                    require("css-mqpacker")
                  ])
              }
            },
            {
              loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: ifNotProduction()
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          commons: {
            name: "commons",
            chunks: "initial",
            minChunks: 2,
            minSize: 0
          },
          styles: {
            name: "styles",
            test: /\.css$/,
            chunks: "all",
            enforce: true
          }
        }
      },
      occurrenceOrder: true 
    },
    plugins: [
      new VueLoaderPlugin(),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "style.[hash].css"
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: true,
        inject: false,
        template: "./src/jinja-templates/base.html.j2",
        filename: `${templates}/base.html.j2`,
      })
    ]
  };
};
```

The .vue file I'm using is this [demo one](https://github.com/dushyant89/vue-webpack/blob/master/src/views/main-content.vue).  I'm trying to import it into the entrypoint called 'testview' which contains simply:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import MainContent from "../components/main-content";
let MainComponent = Vue.extend(MainContent);
new MainComponent().$mount("#mainContent");
```

Answer (score 3):

Did figure it out.  I had to remove `sideEffects: false` from my package.json.  This [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6741) explains it  further.

Still would like to know how to extract the .vue styles to my main stylesheet  As it is now, the .vue styles are extracting to a separate stylesheet (dev and production).